# Property of polynomials proof

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let$$P(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kz^k=a_0+a_1z+...+a_nz^n$$ be an N-th degree polynomial of a complex variable z, where the $a_k$ are complex constants. Now,$$\vert a_0\vert-\vert a_1\vert x-...-\vert a_n\vert x^n=0$$Has exactly one root, $r$, for $x \in [0,\infty)$. Given this, how could one prove that $$P(z)\neq 0 \ \text{for} \ \vert z\vert \lt r$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triangle inequality:  $$|P(z)| \ge |a_0| - |a_1| |z| - \ldots - |a_n| |z|^n$$

Comment: Ugh, this was truly a smack myself in the head kind of moment, thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Using both sides of triangular inequality you have :

$$|P(z)|\geq |a_0|-|a_1z+...a_nz^n|\geq |a_0|-(|a_1||z|+...|a_n||z|^n) $$

Hence if :

$$f(x):=|a_0|-|a_1|x-...-|a_n|x^n $$

You will have that :

$$|P(z)|\geq f(|z|) $$

Now you just have to find a way to justify that $f(x)>0$ for $x\in (0,r)$.